# How to shift pixel value to the next mousemove position in canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I am creating a smudging tool with HTML5 canvas. Now I have to shift the pixel color at the point of mouse pointer to the next position where mouse pointer moves. Is it possible to do with javascript?

```
<canvas id="canvas"><canvas>
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var url = 'download.jpg';
var imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.src = url;
imgObj.onload = function(e) {
  context.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
}

function findPos(obj) {
  var curleft = 0,
    curtop = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
      curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return {
      x: curleft,
      y: curtop
    };
  }
  return undefined;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
    throw "Invalid color component";
  return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}

$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
  var pos = findPos(this);
  var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
  var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
  console.log(x, y);
  var c = this.getContext('2d');
  var p = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
  var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
  console.log(hex)
});
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to create a small offscreen canvas just a little larger than the brush size. Render the part of the canvas you want to move onto that canvas. Use a gradient and destination-in to feather the copied brush then render that offscreen canvas back at the next mouse position, Then repeat. That will be much faster and give better results than doing pixel by pixel.

Comment: @Blindman67 Thats a better idea.Any reference code is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very short on time ATM so code only.

Uses an offscreen canvas `brush` to get a copy of the background canvas `background` where the mouse was last frame. Then use  a radial gradient to feather the brush using `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in"`. Then draw the updated brush at the next mouse position.

The main canvas is use just to display, the canvas being smeared is called `background`  You can put whatever content you want on that canvas (eg image) and it can be any size, and you can zoom, pan, rotate the background though you will have to convert the mouse coordinates to match the background  coordinates

#### Click drag mouse to smear colours.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const background = createCanvas(canvas.width,canvas.height);
const brushSize = 64;
const bs = brushSize;
const bsh = bs / 2;
const smudgeAmount = 0.25; // values from 0 none to 1 full

 // helpers
const doFor = (count, cb) => { var i = 0; while (i < count && cb(i++) !== true); }; // the ; after while loop is important don't remove
const randI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0;


// simple mouse
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false}
function mouseEvents(e){
 mouse.x = e.pageX;
 mouse.y = e.pageY;
 mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse"+name,mouseEvents));


// brush gradient for feather
const grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(bsh,bsh,0,bsh,bsh,bsh);
grad.addColorStop(0,"black");
grad.addColorStop(1,"rgba(0,0,0,0)");
const brush = createCanvas(brushSize)

// creates an offscreen canvas
function createCanvas(w,h = w){
  var c = document.createElement("canvas");
  c.width = w;
  c.height = h;
  c.ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  return c;
}

// get the brush from source ctx at x,y
function brushFrom(ctx,x,y){
  brush.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  brush.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  brush.ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas,-(x - bsh),-(y - bsh));
  brush.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
  brush.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  brush.ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  brush.ctx.fillRect(0,0,bs,bs);
}
  
  



    
// short cut vars 
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2;  // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var globalTime;
var lastX;
var lastY;

// update background is size changed
function createBackground(){
  background.width = w;
  background.height = h;
  background.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  background.ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
  doFor(64,()=>{
    background.ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${randI(255)},${randI(255)},${randI(255)}`;
    background.ctx.fillRect(randI(w),randI(h),randI(10,100),randI(10,100));
  });
}



// main update function
function update(timer){
    globalTime = timer;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
 if(w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
  cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
  ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
    createBackground();
 }else{
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
 }
  ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);


  // if mouse down then do the smudge for all pixels between last mouse and mouse now
  if(mouse.button){
    brush.ctx.globalAlpha = smudgeAmount;
    var dx = mouse.x - lastX;
    var dy = mouse.y - lastY;
    var dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    for(var i = 0;i < dist; i += 1){
      var ni = i / dist;
      brushFrom(background.ctx,lastX + dx * ni,lastY + dy * ni);
      ni = (i+1) / dist;
      background.ctx.drawImage(brush,lastX + dx * ni - bsh,lastY + dy * ni - bsh);
    }
    
  }else{
     brush.ctx.clearRect(0,0,bs,bs); /// clear brush if not used
  }
 
 lastX = mouse.x;
 lastY = mouse.y;
 
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Sir,How to set the image as a jpg or png image

Comment: @AjithVManali Use `const image = new Image; image.src = "url"; image.onload = background.width = image.width; background.height = image.height; background.ctx.drawImage(image,0,0)` and remove the function `createBackground` and call to the function. This now sets the background to hold the image.

Comment: Can we replace the smudge effect with pure pixel color?

Comment: @AjithVManali Do you understand how this answer works?? Just change the line `brush.ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas,-(x - bsh),-(y - bsh));`  in function `brushFrom` to the following two lines `brush.ctx.fillStyle = theColorYouWant;`  and `brush.ctx.fillRect(0,0,bs,bs);`

Comment: It works well.Is it possible to draw only a selected portion of the canvas?

Comment: Yes use the context clip function to set a clip region. Define the clip with a shape (any shape/path) then call clip. First save state so you can undo the clip `ctx.save()`  then create the clip  path, `ctx.beginPath(); ctx.rect(left, top, width, height);` Then call the clip function `ctx.clip()` now only what is inside the area defined by rect can be drawn to. To remove the clip you will need to call `ctx.restore()`